# Automapper cannot convert to a type

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, automapper

I am getting "Cannot Convert type 'PlanEntity' to 'TDestination'" compile time error while mocking my auto mapper in Unit Tests.

```
public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source) where TDestination : class
            {
                var value = source as PlanEntity;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    return (TDestination)value;
                }

                return null;

            }
```

However when I map IEnumerable it is running just fine.

```
public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source) where TDestination : class
            {
                var value = source as IEnumerable<PlanEntity>;

                if (value != null)
                {
                    var results = value.Select(i =>
                        new PlanModel
                        {
                            Id = i.Id,
                            Name = i.Name
                        });

                    return (TDestination)results;
                }

                return null;
            }
```

I have also tried doing this but it is giving the same error.

```
public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source) where TDestination : class
            {
                var value = source as PlanEntity;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    var planModel = new PlanModel
                    {
                        Id = value.Id,
                        Name = value.Name
                    };
                    return (TDestination)planModel;
                }

                return null;

            }
```

There are three overrides in my mockMapper class.

```
TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source) where TDestination : class;
TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination) where TDestination : class;
TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source) where TDestination : class;
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

`var value = source as PlanEntity` is assigning the source to the 'value' variable. However, you later try to cast this to the destination type - `return (TDestination)value;` These types will be different, causing your error.

In your first code block, you would need to add the following to make it equivalent to the second code block:

```
var planModel = new PlanModel() { Id = value.Id };
return (TDestination)planModel;
```

Comment: TDestination is nothing but my PlanModel so the final return statement should be like this at runtime (PlanModel)planEntity. It should work fine like it is working for Collection of PlanEntity in second method.

Comment: Unless `PlanModel` inherits from `PlanEntity`, the cast will not work. Your second code block is casting `PlanModel` to the `TDestination` type, which is presumably `PlanModel`.

Comment: @S7H I've updated my answer, showing how to make the first code block equivalent to the second.

Comment: I got what you are trying to say. you are converting PlanEntity to PlanModel. but .Select will not work on value as it is a single object and not a collection of object. 
I have already tried to do that by doing it another way. But it gives the same error, only difference is PlanEntity is replaced by PlanModel now. 
 "Cannot Convert type 'PlanModel' to 'TDestination'"

Comment: I noticed that myself and updated the answer. How are you using the Map method in your unit test?

Comment: There are three overrides in my mockMapper class.
I am adding those to my questions for better clarity.

Comment: If you enter a breakpoint at the cast, what is the type of `TDestination`?

Comment: I cannot debug the code, I am getting compile time error. 
I am really confused why it is working fine for collection and not for a single element.

Comment: Try returning a collection of `PlanModel` in your mock e.g. `new [] { new PlanModel() { Id = value.Id }`. I suspect the type of `TDestination` is `IEnumerable<PlanModel>`.